# How to change opacity of all Ionic pop-ups

Tags: css, ionic-framework, opacity

How can I change the opacity of all Ionic pop-ups in my project? i.e. `$ionicPopup.show()`. I've tried adding the following entries to `www/style.css` in various combinations but to no avail.

```
.popup {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.popup-body {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.popup {
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
}

.popup-body {
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery code should change the opacity of the class `.popup` on click. Does this work for you? If not, please post more code. Check out this JS Fiddle:

[Opacity Fiddle N1](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26040/)

```
$(".clicker").click(function(){
   $("#first").css('opacity', '0.2');
   $("#second").css('opacity', '0.2');
});
```

Comment: Where would I put this code? I haven't used any jQuery code in my project thus far.

Comment: @Dan how about now?

Comment: I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't use a custom CSS class, but instead overrides the existing Ionic CSS classes that define the behavior of Ionic's popups.

Comment: copy the code and replace the custom written classes by me with YOUR classes. It's not that hard. The provided JS fiddle aims at showing you how it's done, edited the code by changing the names and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out using the Google Chrome Developer Tools remote debugger and element inspector.

I added this to `www/style.css`:

```
.popup-container > .popup {
  background: white;
}
```

Thank you for your effort, @ZombieChowder.